# iOS Adding IBAction Global Method

Tags: ios, crash, global-variables, selector

I am adding a toolbar to certain views but I have the method in GeneralFunctions so that I can pass a view through to add it.

```
+ (void)addCommentsBar:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0, view.frame.size.height - 50);

    UIView *commentsView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, 320, 50)];
    commentsView.backgroundColor = [PitcheroColours pitcheroBlue];

    UILabel *commentsTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 2, 200, 50)];
    commentsTitle.text = @"1 Comment";
    commentsTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton *tapComments = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    tapComments.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tapComments addTarget:self action:@selector(tapComments:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [commentsView addSubview:commentsTitle];
    [commentsView addSubview:tapComments];

    [view addSubview:commentsView];
}
```

When pressed it calls tapComments:

```
- (IBAction)tapComments:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Done");
}
```

Which is sat inside the GeneralFunctions, but it crashes saying:

```
Uncaught exception: +[GeneralFunctions tapComments:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2d5b7c
```

I know it's because I am calling the selector away from the view, however what is best practice to achieve this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addCommentsBar:` method is class method not a instance method. In this you are adding target by

```
 [tapComments addTarget:self action:@selector(tapComments:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

As this method is class method, `self` it will considered as a `class` not a instance of that class. And then you are passing selector as `tapComments:` which is instance method.

So either you pass target as parameter or declare `tapComments:` method as a class method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access from few classes (say 1 or 2) it's better to use delegate. But if you have more classes to have access to your global source , then make that global using singleton pattern.
So, in my view, it's better to make use of singleton in your case.